# Google Chrome -- Google search json download

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-search

Alright so about every 30 seconds that I type searches into google's automatic search engine, google chrome downloads these "search.json" files.  Why are they downloading and what can I do to prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by [FastestChrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmffncokckfccddfenhkhnllmlobdahm).  The solution is to disable it (**"Tools" >> "Extensions" >> "FastestChrome - Browse Faster" >> Uncheck "Enabled"**).  There seems to be a consensus on [a Google forum topic](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4rAd5jl6pqE) that FastestChrome is causing the issue.  I have confirmed myself.

Additionally, Mozilla Firefox users with [FastestFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastestfox-browse-faster/) do experience the same issue.  Disabling FastestFox should also resolve the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it without disabling the entire extension?

Answer (score 0):

The consensus is that FastestChrome causes this issue. Though you don't have to delete the entire app. The google product forums () suggest turning off these features in FastestChrome's options to get rid of the problem:

-Popup Bubble / Search Engines: uncheck google AND Google Maps. 
-Uncheck the boxes under the Search Results tab

Answer (score -1):

goto [Google Preferences](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en)

check "Do not use Google Instant" in Google Instant section

then click save preference button at the right bottom corner.

Comment: That's one approach.  However, it has not always been like this and google instant search is very helpful for my usage.  Call me lazy, haha.